# Android Slide down to up and up to down

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on Dialog and I want to animate it from down to up and up to down.
I tried with this code:
**bottom_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="125%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

**bottom_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Above code animate dialog to center of screen.
But I need that slide up from bottom but align with bottom. and slide down.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try This For Slide Down:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<translate android:fromYDelta="-200%" 
android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

And just reverse of it for Slide Up.

Comment: but its working for me. nothing is happening when you are using this. http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/04/listview-animation-tutorial.html